# Why does the cervical vertebrae contain more white matter than the more lower parts of the spinal cord?

Tags: central-nervous-system

Why does the cervical vertebrae contain more white matter than the more lower parts of the spinal cord, like the lumar vertebrae?

In white matter are the axons of interneurons.

Anyone know this?

Comment: This is true according to my book, but why?

Comment: Try thinking about where those axons are going and where they are coming from, does that help?

Comment: They signals come from the receptors and go to the brain and then they get back to the muscles/glands. But I dont see why you would need more axons around your neck, instead of your trunk, because thats where most body parts are.

Comment: Try drawing a simple diagram where you connect the brain to muscles in the body with wires, and in another color from the peripheral receptors to the brain, and see what it looks like.

Comment: Btw I am Dutch. Peripheral means in the non-central nerve system right?

Comment: Yes - for this exercise it doesn't really matter though. You will get the same answer even if you just draw the axons going to muscles.

Comment: Still dont get it, could you just give the reason?

Comment: The neck part has more receptors?

Comment: I think I know it: there is more white matter upwards because there all the axons meet up, causing it to be more white, due to myelinated cells of Schwann?

Comment: Yep, pretty much. There are more axons in the neck because it has to contain all the fibers from all the rest of the body heading to the brain. Axons in the spinal cord make up "white matter" because they are mostly myelinated, and myelin is white. Since you've figured it out you could write it up as an answer and answer your own question here.

Answer (score -1):

There is more white matter upwards because there all the axons meet up, causing it to be more white, due to myelinated cells of Schwann.

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE! I'm sorry you're not receiving a more positive response to your first posts, but I encourage you to persevere — as a first step please take the [tour] and then consult the help pages for additional advice on [Answer] and [Ask] questions effectively on this site. ——— Specifically, this answer sounds reasonable, but it is much more likely to receive a favorable response if you include supporting references (primary literature is best, but a textbook available online would seem sufficient for this question). Thanks! 